# How do I send a message to stderr from cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a standard windows .cmd file I can send messages to stdout simply by doing:

```
echo message
```

How can I send a message to stderr?

**Example**:

Let's say I have the script parent.cmd containing:

```
call child.cmd 1>>stdout.log 2>>stderr.log
```

and a child containing:

```
:: Writes a message to stdout 
:: (which in the parent is piped to stdout.log)
echo message

:: Now I want to write a message to stderr 
:: (which in the parent is piped to stderr.log)
???
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can try redirecting the handle of STDOUT to the handle of STDERR. In your child process, perform the echo with a handle redirect:

```
:: Writes a message to stdout 
:: (which in the parent is piped to stdout.log)
echo message

:: Now I want to write a message to stderr 
:: (which in the parent is piped to stderr.log)
echo message 1>&2
```

[Microsoft 'splainin it](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225062127/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 27):

Try `echo message 1>&2`

I've just tried this and it seems to work correctly, even from within a batch file.

Comment: this adds an extra empty space at the end of message though...